# change mysql stored procedure to accept mysql field?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I found the below procedure and have edited it a bit - trying to figure out how i can set variable str to a query result 'tags' --(Select tags from Post where id > 3) so I can create the temp table from its contents... nothing I do seems to help.

```
BEGIN

  DECLARE a INT Default 0 ;
  DECLARE str VARCHAR(255);



  simple_loop: LOOP
     SET a=a+1;
     SET str=SPLIT_STR(fullstr,",",a);
     IF str='' THEN
        LEAVE simple_loop;
     END IF;

     insert into Tmp values (str);

   END LOOP simple_loop;
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Select Into statement will do that.

```
BEGIN

  DECLARE a INT Default 0 ;
  DECLARE str VARCHAR(255);

  simple_loop: LOOP
     SET a=a+1;
     Select tags into str from Post where id > 3;
     SET str=SPLIT_STR(str,",",a);
     IF str='' THEN
       LEAVE simple_loop;
     END IF;

     insert into Tmp values (str);

  END LOOP simple_loop;
END
```

Comment: I tried that but it gives me the error that it returns more than one row?

Comment: Not sure about this, but maybe what you need is just a query like:   INSERT INTO Tmp SELECT SPLIT_STR(tags, ", ", 1) from Post where id > 3.

Comment: Yes that gets the first value from tags, but some of the rows for tags have up to 33 values separated with commas, hence the need for a loop.